# Using TaskGroup for removing entries from persisted store when interacting with SwiftUI List

Tags: swift, swiftui, async-await, swiftui-list

I have a SwiftUI `List` where removal is enabled.

`.onDelete` modifier applied to `ForEach` accepts an `IndexSet`.

```
.onDelete { indexSet in
    viewModel.remove(indexSet: IndexSet)
}
```

On the contrary, the store where the items are saved can deal with just one item removal at the time. The view model invoked from the view that contains the `List` and that performs the removal has been coded like the following:

```
func remove(indexSet: IndexSet) async throws {
    let items = await store.items

    return try await withThrowingTaskGroup(of: Void.self) { group in
        for index in indexSet {
            group.addTask {
                let item = items[index]
                try await self.store.remove(item)
            }
        }
        
        try await group.waitForAll()
    }
}
```

Do you think that leveraging `TaskGroup` is the best way to accomplish deletion of an item once at the time?

Comment: `TaskGroup` does the work simultaneously not 1x1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`TaskGroup` does the opposite, it performs multiple tasks concurrently.

Just remove the items with a standard loop, however iterate the indices backwards to avoid index chaos.

```
func remove(indexSet: IndexSet) async throws {
    let items = await store.items
    for index in indexSet.reversed() {
        let item = items[index]
        try await self.store.remove(item)
    }
}
```

I recommend also to check if the last index of the index set is less than the number of items in the array for example

```
guard !indexSet.isEmpty, indexSet.last! < items.count else { return }
```